# cURL error 35: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: curl, magento2, php-openssl

I have installed magento cloud CLI on my local machine when I run `magento-cloud` the welcome note is showing but there is curl error after the welcome note.

[image]

I try different solutions like update curl,ssl, etc. but still nothing happen.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -V` and `openssl version`?

Comment: `curl -V `
**Output:**
`url 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.6.5 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.1
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz HTTP2 UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy`

`openssl version`
**Output:** 
OpenSSL 1.0.2s  28 May 2019`

Comment: It looks like your `cURL` isn't compiled with `OpenSSL`, so I think you'll want to grab one that does. I have the `MacPorts` version installed, which includes it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the version of `cURL` you are using doesn't include `OpenSSL`, so you'll probably want to install or compile one that does. `MacPorts` is the way I would recommend:

1. [Install MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php)

Once installed open terminal:

```
$ sudo port install curl
```

After installing you should get something similar to:

```
$ curl -V
curl 7.65.3 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0) libcurl/7.65.3 OpenSSL/1.0.2s zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.2.0 libpsl/0.21.0 (+libidn2/2.1.1)
Release-Date: 2019-07-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Largefile libz NTLM NTLM_WB PSL SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets

$ which curl
/opt/local/bin/curl
```

Comment: already done installing Macport and got same result as yours but still getting same error:

 **[ConnectException]
  cURL error 35: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version** when . I run `magento-cloud` on CLI.

Comment: @magerez: Can you show the output again of `curl -V`? Also restart your Terminal.